# PHP Form Processing Order precedence

Tags: php, forms, field, hidden, checkbox

Am new to the world of development and am just starting to pick up PHP. I have basic form that attempts to validate the checkboxes the user has selected or checked. My code is below. The question I have is why is that when I have the order of my form as follows, the form does not pass the value NET, PHP or RUBY and the values that are costantly passed are no.

--- Form code that does not work ---

```
<form name="checkboxes" method="post" action="form_sample_checkboxes.php">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="net" <?php print $ch1status ?>>.NET
            <input type="hidden" name="ch1" value="no">


        <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="php" <?php print $ch2status ?>>PHP
        <input type="hidden" name="ch2" value="no">


        <input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ruby" <?php print $ch3status ?>>Ruby on Rails
        <input type="hidden" name="ch3" value="no">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

However if my code is as follows;

```
<form name="checkboxes" method="post" action="form_sample_checkboxes.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ch1" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="net" <?php print $ch1status ?>>.NET

        <input type="hidden" name="ch2" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="php" <?php print $ch2status ?>>PHP

        <input type="hidden" name="ch3" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ruby" <?php print $ch3status ?>>Ruby on Rails

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

The boxes appear checked. The entire code below.

```
<?php

$ch1status = "unchecked";
$ch2status = "unchecked";
$ch3status = "unchecked";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        if(isset($_POST["ch1"])) {
            if($_POST["ch1"] == "net") {
                $ch1status = "checked";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["ch2"])) {
            if($_POST["ch2"] == "php") {
                $ch2status = "checked";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["ch3"])) {
            if($_POST["ch3"] == "ruby") {
                $ch3status = "checked";
            }
        }

        if ($_POST["ch1"] == "no" && $_POST["ch2"] == "no" && $_POST["ch3"] == "no") {
            print "There is no such choice";
        }

}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample form checkbxoes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="checkboxes" method="post" action="form_sample_checkboxes.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ch1" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="net" <?php print $ch1status ?>>.NET

        <input type="hidden" name="ch2" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="php" <?php print $ch2status ?>>PHP

        <input type="hidden" name="ch3" value="no">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ruby" <?php print $ch3status ?>>Ruby on Rails

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if(isset($_POST["ch1"])) {
        print $_POST["ch1"];
        print $ch1status;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["ch2"])) {
        print $_POST["ch2"];
        print $ch2status;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["ch3"])) {
        print $_POST["ch3"];
        print $ch3status;
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

?>

</body>
</html>
        </form>
```

Also is there any other way of validating if the user has not selected any checkboxes as opposed to using hidden form fields.

Answer (score 1):

## UNDEFINED INDEXES:

This is because checkboxes are only sent if they are checked.  One thing you can do is always check the variable with isset (e.g. `isset($_POST['ch1'])`) before using them; another is to name your checkboxes the same thing with a `[]` following the name (e.g. `name="languages[]"`) and then do something like this:

```
// Create a list of languages that are OK (remember, some users are malicious)
$languages = array('net','php','ruby');
// Compile a list of the answers the user picked; force it to be an 
// array by either explicitly casting to an array, or using an empty array
//  if none chosen
$picked = isset($_POST['languages']) ? (array)$_POST['languages'] : array();

// first, use array_intersect to remove entries present in one and not the other
// i.e. invalid entries from the client or entries not picked from the whole list
// then, "flip" the array so that the values become keys, 
// because isset is faster than in_array
$valid_langs = array_flip(array_intersect($languages, $picked));

// check on languages
if (isset($valid_langs['php'])) { /* PHP picked */ }
if (isset($valid_langs['net'])) { /* NET picked */ }
if (isset($valid_langs['ruby'])) { /* Ruby picked */ }
```

### Simpler Solution:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="php" value="yes" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="net" value="yes" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ruby" value="yes" />
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
$php = $net = $ruby = 'unchecked';
if (!isset($_POST['php'],$_POST['net'],$_POST['ruby'])) {
    echo 'There is no such choice';
}
else {
    if (isset($_POST['php']) && $_POST['php'] == 'yes') {
        $php = 'checked';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['net']) && $_POST['new'] == 'yes') {
        $net = 'checked';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ruby']) && $_POST['ruby'] == 'yes') {
        $ruby = 'checked';
    }
}
// ... snip ...
```

There are a great many ways to do this.  Hopefully you will be interested in learning many of them.

Comment: Whow. That just flew past my head. Have no idea how arrays work nor statements such as $picked = isset($_POST['languages']) ? (array)$_POST['languages'] : array();. Is there something simpler for a beginner whilst I pick up what arrays are, how they work, etc?

Comment: I've added in a simpler solution, though it's worth mentioning that `$_POST` is an array, so you're not entirely unfamiliar with them =)

Comment: Wow, seems so much cleaner than my code. A question. 

1. Why the declaration $php = $net = $ruby = 'unchecked'; 

I had no idea you could write isset($_POST['php'],$_POST['net'],$_POST['ruby']. 

I know that $_POST is an array however I don't know what an array does, when you use it, etc.

Comment: That's to initialize them beforehand, not really necessary in PHP, unless of course there could be a logic error later on if they aren't set, such as if they are only set in an if condition that doesn't trigger and are used in an if condition later on.

Comment: Sorry Phoenix. I didn't quite follow what you meant. Could you please elaborate? Sorry am a beginner.

Comment: I can explain what Phoenix meant.  Say you have some variable(s) which are only declared inside of a conditional statement, e.g. `if ($foo == $bar) { $condition = true; }`; if `$condition` isn't defined as false anywhere else, and you attempt to check it without using `isset()` first, PHP will throw an undefined variable warning.  The declaration I used assigns all of the variables to the same value, 'unchecked', so that I can check to see if they have had a different value assigned later, which would only happen as the result of conditional logic (`if` statements, etc).

Comment: Arrays, by the way, are some of the most important things you can learn in PHP; some might say that PHP is an array-oriented language, given their strength.  You can think of them as collections of variables, since any array element can have any value, even another array.  Defining an array is easy, you can either do `array('foo','bar')` which will set index '0' to 'foo' and '1' to 'bar', or you can manually assign the index (which can be any valid string or number) by using the `=>` operator, e.g. `array('foo' => 'bar')`.  The way you are using `$_POST` is the same way you use any array.

Comment: @Monkey: If this answer "flew past [your] head", perhaps it's time for you to read a good PHP book (which should have been your first port of call anyway, before you started coding) so that you can pick up the language's basics.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a browser-issue and its quite simple: The elements have the same name and the later element overwrites the first one.

Another way of validating, if a checkbox is not checked is to check, if its set in the `$POST`-array. If its missing, its treated like "not checked".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need those hidden fields. Remove them and it should work.

**EDIT:**
Check out this modification

```
    $ch1status = "unchecked";
    $ch2status = "unchecked";
    $ch3status = "unchecked";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        if(@$_POST["ch1"] != "") {
            $ch1status = "checked";
        }

        if(@$_POST["ch2"] != "") {
            $ch2status = "checked";
        }

        if(@$_POST["ch3"] != "") {
            $ch3status = "checked";
        }

        if (@$_POST["ch1"] . @$_POST["ch2"] . @$_POST["ch3"] == "") {
            print "There is no such choice";
        }

    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample form checkbxoes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="checkboxes" method="post" action="form_sample_checkboxes.php">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="net" <?php echo $ch1status; ?>>.NET

            <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="php" <?php echo $ch2status; ?>>PHP

            <input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ruby" <?php echo $ch3status; ?>>Ruby on Rails

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php

            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                if(isset($_POST["ch1"])) {
                    print $_POST["ch1"];
                    print $ch1status;
                }

                if(isset($_POST["ch2"])) {
                    print $_POST["ch2"];
                    print $ch2status;
                }

                if(isset($_POST["ch3"])) {
                    print $_POST["ch3"];
                    print $ch3status;
                }

            }

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "</pre>";

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They don't. If I don't have the hidden form fields all I am displayed undefined index errors.

Comment: use `isset($_POST['php'])`, etc, to verify the fields exist before trying to work with them.  Checkboxes only create POST variables if they are checked.

Comment: Thanks Dereleased however how do I use isset($_POST[]) with the statement "($_POST["ch1"] == "no" && $_POST["ch2"] == "no" && $_POST["ch3"] == "no")" i.e. how do I validate multiple form fields at the same time?

Comment: You have to do each individually. eg. if(isset($_POST['ch2'])) //do stuff

Comment: actually, `isset()` and `unset()` will both accept multiple arguments, e.g. `isset($_POST['ch1'],$_POST['ch2'],$_POST['ch3'])` -- note, this is pass/fail; if even one is not set, it returns false; it is also subject to short-circuit logic.

Comment: Thanks Derelease. Could you break it down to me what you meant here "actually, isset() and unset() will both accept multiple arguments, e.g. isset($_POST['ch1'],$_POST['ch2'],$_POST['ch3']) -- note, this is pass/fail; if even one is not set, it returns false; it is also subject to short-circuit log". For example what do you mean when you say that if even one is not set, it returns false as well as what you mean by short-circuit logic?

Comment: Thanks Craig. What does the @ symbol mean and do i.e. @$_POST["ch1"] . @$_POST["ch2"] . @$_POST["ch3"] == ""?

Comment: putting an @ symbol prevents an error from occuring when a value/function does not exist. Instead if the value doesnt exist it will return "".

Comment: The dot with the multiple varaibles joins/concat them. eg. "php".""."test" = "phptest"

Comment: Didn't even know I could concantenate statements e.g.  @$_POST["ch1"] . @$_POST["ch2"] . @$_POST["ch3"].

Comment: They are just string arrays after all. $_POST is the same as any other array just that it's prefilled.

Answer (score 0):

Php is all server-side, so in order to keep them from submitting you'll need client-side validation.  Easiest client-side validation is with javascript, or jQuery's [Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) if you're already using jQuery (which you should be if you plan on using AJAX at any point).

And yes, you can get rid of those hidden inputs.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Yes am aware that it is all server-side and I can use client-side validation however would like to learn how to validate data server side.

Comment: Also if I remove the hidden form fields, I get undefined index errors.

Comment: Never trust the client?  Really?  I've found that client-side validation is a necessity.  Ideally you use both, of course, but to dismiss it altogether is kinda dumb, especially when dealing with form submission.  Block the submission at the client level and you save server load.  Or are you the kind of guy who rolls with no CAPTCHA?